# reading spatial data in spark 2 with megallen

Tags: scala, apache-spark, geospatial

Im trying to create the simplest udf to transform lat,long values to that I get from JDBC connection to magellan point UDT

I tried something like this( Spark 2.1):

```
val spark = SparkSession
        .builder()
        .master("local[2]")
        .getOrCreate()
      import spark.implicits._
      import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
      val df =  Seq((30.1,32.2,new PointUDT())).toDF("lat","long","point")
      val toPointUDF = udf{(x:Double,y:Double) => new PointUDT.serialize(Point(x,y)) }
      val result = df.withColumn("point",toPointUDF($"point")).take(1)
      result must beEqualTo(Point(30,10))
```

unfortunately it not passing compilation...
getting the "PointUDT is inaccessible from this place"

how can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem now.
I am trying to create a PostGIS point from lat lon.

I need to merge this into an existing table. 
I also have the problem that I did not find a simple way to do upsert = insert/update.

The best solution I have so far is to write output to a temporary table. Delete duplicates in the temporary table and do an upsert from the temporary table to the target table that also convert lat lon to PostGIS geometry column.